# Pkg-config 0.28 did not build on OSX 10.10.2

Tags: homebrew, osx-yosemite, pkg-config, gcc4.9

Recently I clean installed Yosemite 10.10.2

I also installed gcc using

```
brew install gcc
```

Now I'm trying to build and install `python` and `openmpi` from source because previously I've had problems with `gfortran` and `clang`.

So I did

```
brew install openmpi --build-from-source -verbose 
brew install python --build-from-source -verbose
```

with variables and aliases:

```
export CC=gcc-4.9
export CXX=g++-4.9
export CPP=g++-4.9
export LD=gcc-4.9
export FC=gfortran-4.9
export HOMEBREW_CC=gcc-4.9
export HOMEBREW_LD=gcc-4.9
export HOMEBREW_CXX=g++-4.9
export HOMEBREW_CPP=g++-4.9
export HOMEBREW_FC=gfortran
alias cc=gcc-4.9
alias gcc=gcc-4.9
alias c++=c++-4.9
alias g++=g++-4.9
```

Still getting the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:51:0,
             from        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:13,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:55,
             from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19,
             from gunicollate.c:30:
/usr/include/dispatch/object.h:143:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before '^' token
typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);

/usr/include/dispatch/object.h:362:3: error: unknown type name 'dispatch_block_t'
dispatch_block_t notification_block);

==> Formula
Path: /usr/local/Library/Formula/pkg-config.rb
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: 9bbd6637009256d70b57691c3ad1979ca2bb5916
Last commit: 9 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.10.2-x86_64
Xcode: 6.2
CLT: 6.2.0.0.1.1424975374
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
Java: 1.6.0_65
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: gcc-4.9
HOMEBREW_CXX: g++-4.9
MAKEFLAGS: -j2
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/libxml2:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/apache2:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10
HOMEBREW_SDKROOT: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin

Error: pkg-config 0.28 did not build
```

My understanding is that there is a conflict between `clang` and `gcc-4.9` configuration.

I could temporally solve it doing:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

So it doesn't build if from source and uses clang configuration.

I see that Xcode is still in the Include and Library path, and I think this prevents linking with gcc-4.9.

How can I install `pkg-config` using `gcc-4.9` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after following this [instructions](http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/osx-gcc-dispatch_block_t-has-not-been-declared-invalid-typedef/) changing:

```
typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void); // this is for clang
```

To

```
typedef void* dispatch_block_t;  //this is for gcc-4.9
```